# Give access to pages to specific user types PHP

Tags: php

In my application I have 2 user types, admin and manager. I want the manager to have access to the `dashboard.php` only. For this in my `users` table I've set `usertype` as column and while signing up they have to mention what type of user they are. Based on this, after logging in the manager dashboard, I have a button that goes to `dashboard.php`. And in `dashboard.php` I'm checking the `$_SESSION['usertype'] == 'manager')`. If it is it'll allow the user to access that page otherwise it'll take him to login page. But it isn't working. Every time it is taking me to the login page and anyone can access the `dashboard.php` by putting in the URL.

**manager.php**

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

echo $_SESSION["usertype"];
?>
 
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; text-align: center; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="my-5">Welcome, <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["usertype"]); ?></b>. All System Operational!</h1>
    <p>
        <a href='dashboard.php' class="btn btn-primary">Inventory Management</a>
        <a href="reset-password.php" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset Your Password</a>
        <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Out of Your Account</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Dashboard.php**

```
<?php

if ((isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION['usertype'] == 'manager')) {
   header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
} else {
    header('Location: login.php');
}

?>
...
```

**Login.php**

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
/* what happens if users are different?
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}
*/
 
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$usertype = $password = "";
$usertype_err = $password_err = $login_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Check if usertype is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["usertype"]))){
        $usertype_err = "Please enter usertype.";
    } else{
        $usertype = trim($_POST["usertype"]);
    }
    
    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($usertype_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, usertype, password FROM users WHERE usertype = ?";
        
        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_usertype);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_usertype = $usertype;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // Store result
                $stmt->store_result();
                
                // Check if usertype exists, if yes then verify password
                if($stmt->num_rows == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    $stmt->bind_result($id, $usertype, $hashed_password);
                    if($stmt->fetch()){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();
                            
                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["usertype"] = $usertype;                            
                            
                            if($usertype == "admin"){
                                header("location: welcome_admin.php");
                            } elseif($usertype == "manager"){
                                header("location: welcome_manager.php");
                            }elseif($usertype == "delivery"){
                                header("location: welcome_delivery.php");
                            }
                        } else{
                            // Password is not valid, display a generic error message
                            $login_err = "Invalid usertype or password.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // usertype doesn't exist, display a generic error message
                    $login_err = "Invalid usertype or password.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 360px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>

        <?php 
        if(!empty($login_err)){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $login_err . '</div>';
        }        
        ?>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>User Type</label>
                <input type="text" name="usertype" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($usertype_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $usertype; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $usertype_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So how do I make this `dashboard.php` accessible to specified user type only?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
session_start();

if((isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION['usertype'] == 'manager')){
   header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}else {
    header('Location: login.php');
}

?>
```

use session start to resume the session you build.

> Every page that will use the session information on the website must
> be identified by the session_start() function. This initiates a
> session on each PHP page. The session_start function must be the first
> thing sent to the browser or it won't work properly. It must precede
> any HTML tags.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: At first I had added `session_start()` but then it showed me `This page isn't working` error. That's why I had removed it.

Comment: Is is working now? If its worked for you please accept the answer.

Comment: No..still same `This page isn't working` error.

Comment: The answer shared by @DarkKnight should do the trick. If you are using $_SESSION then the first statement in the page should be session_start().

Comment: @buzz can you please share the login.php code?

Comment: Seems like there is multiple redirection issue in your code.

Comment: @PhanHero added the `login.php`

Comment: login.php has no issue also. I find no issue in your code.

Comment: @PhanHero Yeah I even tried clearing the cookie and restart the server...but no result

Comment: **This page isn't working** maybe from redirect loop. Example: (A -> B -> A -> B -> ...). Make sure that it isn't. That error page should showing the error details such as `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`, `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Comment: @buzz `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` this command will be redirect to itself. If you are on page A then it will be redirect to page A and if conditions are met again then redirect to page A again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by removing the `(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])` checking in `dashboard.php`. Now I'm only checking if the user is manager or not. so it goes like this

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['usertype'] !== "manager"){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

?>
```

I guess logged in state doesn't need to be checked as it is getting already checked in the manager page.